Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "Bags" at [6:8]
soy nuevo en SQL y el problema que me arroja bigquery es lo que tengo puedo en el título.  El código en cuestión es este
SELECT
Small Bags,
Large Bags,
XLarge Bags,
Total Bags
Small Bags + Large Bags + XLarge Bags AS Total_Bags
FROM
palta_data.avocado_prices
y al añadir el caracter ` en la operación, solo me genera una columna más grande con todos los nombres y sin información de la suma en su interior.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Parece que el error es bastante claro, y es debido al uso de nombres de columnas que contienen espacios. Hasta donde sé, en BigQuery, los nombres de columnas con espacios deber estar encerrados entre acentos graves (``) para que se puedan interpretar correctamente.
La consulta debería de verse similar a esto:
SELECT 
    `Small Bags`, 
    `Large Bags`, 
    `XLarge Bags`, 
    `Total Bags`, 
    (`Small Bags` + `Large Bags` + `XLarge Bags`) AS `Total_Bags`
FROM 
    `palta_data.avocado_prices`;

Todos los nombres están cerrados con comillas graves correctamente, además de que te recomiendo que uses alias (como en la consulta) para dar un nombre claro a la nueva columna generada.
